# Оформление слайдера Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, слайдер

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие компоненты выбрать в `customize` на сайте [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), чтобы был весь функционал и оформление слайдера.
И подскажите еще, нужно ли делать разметку для слайдера а-ля:

```
<section id="slider">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
  <!-- Ниже соответственно стандартная разметка слайдера-->
```

Или достаточно просто вставить стандартную разметку, без всяких секций, контейнеров и строк.

Answer (score 3):

На странице кастомизации http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ выбираете в разделе **jQuery plugins** пункт Carousel functionality.
Ниже минимальный код карусели, а уж как ее верстать - дело ваше.

В целом, я бы не рекомендовал начинающим изучение Bootstrap заморачиваться с тонким подбором компонентов, пока не придет осознание, как они работают - для начала работы вполне годится полный (минифицированный) Bootstrap JS и CSS.

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```